# refresh GridView using Client Callback

Tags: asp.net, ajax

How do I refresh GridView using Client CallBack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also have a look at the Jquery grid.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
yourGrid.DataBind()
```

Comment: i want to use Client Callback

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the UpdatePanel and put the complete Grid inside the UpdatePanel?